# How to type-infer PHP-functions with optional arguments

Tags: php, ocaml, type-inference

The thing with PHP is that it doesn't have a specific syntax when using a function with optional arguments. This:

```
foo(10);
```

can either be this

```
function foo($a) {}
```

or this

```
function foo($a = 0) {}
```

or this

```
function foo($a, $b = 0, ...) {}
```

(or even `function foo() {}`, but disregard that for now).

So how do we type-infer it when a function is used before it's defined?

One solution is to record all usages until the definition comes, and then see if they all can unify with it. The example above would then store

```
int -> unit
```

and later check if it's compatible with

```
int -> (typ list) -> unit
```

or whatever (where `typ list` is the list of optional arguments).

You think this could work? Are there other conventional ways to deal with this?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I only skimmed your question but have you looked at reflection? There is some useful functionality like `ReflectionFunction` and `ReflectionParameter` that can tell you how many arguments a function has, its name, if it's optional, its default value (if present) etc.

Comment: OK, maybe I need to give more context. I'm building a type-inferring linter for PHP using the lexer/parser from HHVM. This is done in OCaml. This is more like a theoretical question, really. Thanks, though.

Comment: Ah right. I just posted an answer but it might not be relevant in this case. If it doesn't let me know and I will be glad to delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to either insert "weak" type variables and keep them until function definition is found, or first build a complete AST and then run it through the type inference and raise an error if there are functions whose definitions are unknown (I wonder how would you about built-in functions, perhaps use pre-baked type signature database?).

Comment: Yeah. As mentioned by rks, you can also use a two-phase algorithm where you first sort the functions, and then type them.

Comment: For the built-in functions, yes, their signatures will be added to every new scope/environment while type-inferring. The empty scope includes these, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to what degree this answers your question, but to elaborate on my comment above you could use PHP's built-in suite of reflection classes to help introspect and derive useful information about functions and their arguments.

Specifically, I think [`ReflectionFunction`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) and [`ReflectionParameter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php) could be useful in your case, although there is much more functionality that might help.

For example, here is a very simple example where you want to get some information about a function's arguments:

```
<?php

// a simple function with an
// optional/default argument
function foo($a, $b = 0)
{
    return $a + $b;
}

// create a ReflectionFunction object
// passing the name of the function name.
// you can also pass a variable reference 
// to an anonymous function.
$refl = new ReflectionFunction('foo');

// iterate over the ReflectionFunction's
// parameter list to get a ReflectionParameter
// object for each of foo's arguments. here we're 
// just printing out a __toString() summary of each
// argument.
foreach ($refl->getParameters() as $param) {
    echo $param . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Yields:

```
Parameter #0 [ <required> $a ]
Parameter #1 [ <optional> $b = 0 ]
```

As you can see, this simple example shows some information about `foo`'s argument list: param number, required/optional, var name and default value.

`$param` is an instance of `ReflectionParameter` so there is a bunch of methods you can call on that to get more information about each argument, including:

```
export
__construct
__toString
getName
isPassedByReference
canBePassedByValue
getDeclaringFunction
getDeclaringClass
getClass
isArray
isCallable
allowsNull
getPosition
isOptional
isDefaultValueAvailable
getDefaultValue
isDefaultValueConstant
getDefaultValueConstantName
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm making this project in OCaml, not PHP. :) The only information available is on syntactic level.

Comment: That's fair enough! I will add an OCaml tag to the question. Sounds like interesting work!